# Is "We wish to confirm that this amount has been processed and enclosed is a cheque totalling $15,000.00" grammatically correct

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

I am creating a document that has the following sentence:

> We wish to confirm that this amount has been processed and enclosed **is** a cheque totalling $15,000.00.

From my point of view, using the word *is* seems grammatically incorrect. I'm thinking it should either be *in* or *as*,but I am not 100% sure.

Maybe the problem is that there is some punctuation missing?

> We wish to confirm that this amount has been processed; enclosed **is** a cheque totalling $15,000.00.

Perhaps this sentence should be broken into two sentences?

> 1. We wish to confirm that this amount has been processed.
> 2. We have enclosed a cheque with an amount totalling $15,000.00

What is the correct way to write this sentence?

Comment: Use two sentences. They don't have anything to do with each other. Also, it should be a check/cheque *for* $15,000.00. You don't need *totaling* because there's only one; you don't need to add anything up to arrive at a total.

Comment: I've encountered _enclosed please find_ in this context. You can also use _enclosed herewith is_ —herewith is a fairly unusual word since this exact case is its only common use.

Comment: The sentence is grammatical, semantically correct and very common in business writing.

Comment: @Kris: Are you contending it should be read, "We wish to confirm that (this amount has been processed) and (enclosed is a cheque totalling $15,000.00)." That is, they are confirming those two things? That's about the only way I can see it as grammatical. But why would they send me a letter to confirm that this very letter includes a check? I mean, it's possible. If you contend it's grammatical, please tell me how you think it should be parsed. If you attach "confirm" only to "processed", the only form that makes logical sense, it become ungrammatical.

Comment: Don’t cheques normally come in £, checks in $? :)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz When the two independent clauses make perfect sense to you as already evident from the OP's analysis, what is the problem with the combined sentence using the coordinating conjunction rather than a punctuation? Read again. The use of *and* is conventional, the semicolon in its place is not. Splitting into two independent sentences is semantically invalid.

Comment: We wish to confirm that this amount has been processed and is enclosed as a cheque totalling $15,000.00.

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced that this is a language question. It seems like a proofreading request. Can you clarify what is not grammatical about the sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence is awkward because it's two sentences conjoined into one. Change it from:

> We wish to confirm that this amount has been processed and enclosed is a cheque totalling $15,000.00.

to

> We wish to confirm that this amount has been processed. A {check / bank draft / bank check / cashier's check / cheque [CHOOSE ONE]} {for / in the amount of [CHOOSE ONE]} $15,000.00 is enclosed.

The revised second sentence offers both plain English and business-speak versions that go with the business-speak of the first sentence.

Comment: Thanks Bill, I think I'll go with your recommendation on this one.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence is missing a comma, which causes it to be very hard to parse.

A reader sees "We wish to confirm that this amount has been processed and enclosed" and parses "processed and enclosed" as a unit. When they get to "is a cheque", they try to reparse it to "enclosed is a cheque", but now they're not sure how the first part and the second part of the sentence go together because there's no point at which they can meet.

To correct it, put in the comma: "We wish to confirm that this amount has been processed, and enclosed is a cheque totaling $15,000.00." Now it's clear that the two halves of the meaning of the sentence split at the "and" and it's not possible to group "processed and enclosed" into a unit.

This still might be a bit awkward though, depending on the context. If it is, just split it into two sentences. Also, I'd say "for $15,000.00" rather than "totaling". It seems odd to me for one thing to "total" to something. (Or "in the amount of", as Bill Franke suggests.)

Comment: -1 That is not about grammar, though. These corrections do not help improve readability either. See also my comment at OP above.

Comment: @Kris: You're flat-out wrong about this question. You don't have a clue what it's about. Syntax is one subdivision of grammar. The syntax isn't optimal, & the writing mechanics (punctuation, in this case) are wrong. David's right: stick in the comma he suggests, & the S is easier to read & understand without having to consciously & re-parse parse the sentence. Split it into two sentences, & the syntactic as well as the punctuation problem disappears. That bad writers of business-speak use this kind of shitenglish is no excuse to rationalize it away as acceptable, as you seem to want to.

Comment: @Kris: I see a lot of assertions but frankly, I can't tell why you are asserting any of those things. And I definitely disagree with your claim that my changes don't improve readability. I'm a native speaker and former CTO of a tech company and I had to guess what the original sentence meant. I presented a detailed walkthrough of what actually happened when I tried to understand it and precisely how it was confusing.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz "This still might be a bit awkward though" was not *my* assertion -- and is what prompted my comment "These corrections do not help improve readability either." HTH. I know many who are familiar and comfortable with the usage as in OP's example. You are welcome to ask any more clarifications.

Comment: Thanks David, I appreciate your response even though I'll be going with Bill's answer.